# Rails does not find gem, although it is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I hope somebody can help, I am really confused about this. I want to use the gem svg-graph ([github](https://github.com/lumean/svg-graph2)) within my rails app. But `require 'svggraph'`  gives me this error: `cannot load such file -- svg-graph`, which I don't understand as running a script inside the app folder requiring the gem runs perfectly.

I have `gem 'svg-graph'` within my Gemfile and `bundle installs` ran successfully.

`gem which svggraph` gives me `/Users/Username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/svg-graph-2.1.1/lib/svggraph.rb`.

If it helps here's my output of `gem env`

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.3 (2016-11-21 patchlevel 222) [x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Username/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/Username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/Username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/Username/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
    - /Users/Username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
    - /Users/Username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
    - /Users/Username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin
    - /Users/Username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin
    - /Users/Username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin
    - /usr/bin
    - /bin
    - /usr/sbin
    - /sbin
    - /usr/local/bin
    - /opt/X11/bin
    - /usr/local/git/bin
    - /usr/local/go/bin
    - /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
    - /Library/TeX/texbin
    - /Us
```

ers/Username/.rvm/bin

Comment: I guess restarting the server will do the trick.

Comment: Where do you have `require 'svggraph'` in your code?

Comment: Does it break when starting the rails server or while running the application?

Comment: It's a little embarrassing, but restarting the server actually fixed it...
Sorry for the pointless question and thanks for your help!